# Should I assume my income to increase by 5%?

Tags: salary, united-states, raise

---

Is it reasonable to assume that, regardless if it is a public or private company, a person's income will increase by 5%/yearly? 

Below is the federal student debt assumptions for debt repayment. I've always heard that a person should assume their income will increase at a rate similar or just above inflation. Are there any graphs or studies about this someone can point me to? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: "I've always heard that a person should assume their income will increase ..." Where have you heard that? The original context in which that was said is important to understand what it means. For example, someone trying to sell you an investment scheme might tell you "Assume that your salary always grows at the rate of inflation. You won't really be getting richer. That's why you need this investment scheme." (or some such) In that context, assumed doesn't mean "guaranteed", it means something like "suppose". Reminds me of a mathematician's joke that this comment is too small to contain.

Comment: They make a lot of assumptions.

Comment: If you switch employers every 2-3 years, it should be doable.

Comment: My first employer (at a major company) gave me one 2% raise in 2 years. So, no.

Comment: I wish I got 5% per year.

Comment: No. You can not rely on the estimates and objectivity of a creditor. Their financial interests are not necessarily aligned with yours. Besides, most jumps in salaries appear when you jump from employer to employer. If you're unwilling to move from employer to employer, or unable to, you should assume that the yearly cost of living increase calculated by your employer (if any) will not even keep up with the yearly rate of inflation.

Comment: My income only increased by 3.2% last year, 2.7% the year before and 1.9% the year before that.  In all three cases those raises were marginally above-inflation in my country (UK). So I'm going to say no, it's not a reasonable assumption.   I have, however, recently accepted a new job that represents a 19% increase in salary, so while it's not a reasonable assumption, it is a plausible goal.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no. 5% is probably something like an optimistic average, and in that optimistic picture still half the people would be below that. Some people are able to grow their income much faster and others are much slower.

Since you're getting this from that final paragraph, I'll point out that their other assumption is virtually always wrong: most people's family sizes change after graduating college during their career.

Comment: +1 As an example, the [US federal employee cost of living adjustment](https://www.federalpay.org/gs/raises) has averaged closer to 1.1% over the past 10 years, with 3 of those years being 0%. Granted, this is only cost-of-living and doesn't include any merit increases or promotions, but those are never guaranteed either.

Answer (score 0):

**NO** Unfortunately in the world of work you cannot assume that you will even get a payrise let alone one greater then inflation.

I would assume that the wildly generous estimates you quote have been set politically to flatter the organisation by implying that amount repaid will be higher. Implying that all graduating students wont get married and have kids is another sign of this.

Answer (score 0):

No.  In the past 10 years my average salary increase has been under 2%.  Highest was a little over 6% (right when I was laid off so that was the amount for my severance).

Answer (score -1):

Workload increases by at least 5% per year, minimum (unless they are losing business and on the verge of failure). Pay can increase by 5% if workload exceeds 15% per year.

If pay increases 15% the company is likely to hit a cycle where it's cheaper to hire someone for less and not offer you a raise, causing you to leave. That practice distills a business with people whom are either the least capable or simply  enjoy working for little reward.

The above does not apply at 5% of companies, who value longevity, moral conduct, advertising by word of mouth and good will; the truly honest and successful.

I'd only consider 5% increase in pay likely if the company had such a track record. I'd reject it also, as I'd prefer to work harder and earn more. A raise of ten to fifteen percent is not difficult to earn, just at some places it's difficult or impossible to receive.

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers from? You need citations.